# Floating point division resulting in a value exceeding 1 but should be equal to 1...maybe!

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I am computing the apparent magnitude of comets and minor planets using data from the Minor Planet Center.  The formula I use has a division and that result is passed to the arccosine function (in Python).

Occasionally the result of the division is slightly greater than 1, for example

6.272370848320445 / 6.2723697617591405 = 1.0000001732297912

I assume the result is not actually greater than 1; rather the result is an artefact of floating point arithmetic, particularly given the number of zeros after the decimal point.

If my assumption is correct, I want to catch this sort of situation and treat the result as if the division yielded exactly 1 (and so can safely be passed to arccosine).

If I make an arbitrary choice of say five decimal points and truncate the division result, then if the result is 1 I'm good, otherwise, drop the result.

I'm not sure if what I'm proposing is correct mathematically, so looking for guidance please.  I have assumed this issue arises due to floating point arithmetic, but if that assumption is wrong, then I'm not sure what else I can do.  It is possible the source data from the Minor Planet Center contains spurious data which is causing the actual error (and thus I shouldn't be trying to work around it but just let it fail).

The formula can be found [here](https://www.clearskyinstitute.com/xephem/help/xephem.html#mozTocId564354) (using the H,G model).

Comment: I am curious about why the division result goes to arccosine. Does not makes sense to me now.

Comment: @Somos I have added a link to the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced exactly the same situation with round-off (in calculation of finite rotations in C#). You theoretically know that the division equals maximally to 1 ergo you can implement it as follows:

$\max(-1.0, \min(1.0, x/y))~$ instead of $~x/y$

and your code will be safe.

Comment: This type of situation arises frequently in floating point computation, and this is the best way to handle it.  One needs to keep in mind at all times that every floating point computation is approximate, and code defensively. +1

Answer (score 5):

I looked at the link you mention in your question and I don't
have time to study all of the details. However, the expression

```
beta = acos((rp*rp + rho*rho - rsn*rsn)/(2*rp*rho));
```

seems like an instance of
[Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).
This can be rewritten as

```
beta = acos(1 -(rsn+rho-rp)(rsn-rho+rp)/(2*rp*rho));
```

The problem in computing this is that `rsn+rho-rp` or
`rsn-rho+rp` loses precision if `rsn` and `|rho-rp|`
are of comparable value and may become negative. This
happens when the triangle is close to degenerate where
one of the angles becomes very close to zero. In these
cases you can use the [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)
idea and use the formula

```
beta = 2*asin(sqrt(max(0,(rsn+rho-rp)(rsn-rho+rp)/(4*rp*rho)));
```

or the approximation when the angle is close to zero

```
beta = sqrt(max(0,(rsn+rho-rp)(rsn-rho+rp)/(rp*rho)));
```

where the `max(0,.)` ensures that we don't attempt to
take the square root of a negative number.

Note that the `acos(x)` formula is great when $x$ is
close to zero, but the `asin(x)` formula is better when
$x$ is close to one in absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the numerator is slightly larger than the denominator (look at the fifth decimal place) so that quotient should be greater than $1$.

Pasting the division into the google search bar gives
$1.00000017323$.

Your program is calculating the quotient correctly. If it should be no larger than $1$ the problem is upstream where the data comes from.

Comment: From the question description, it seems that the OP is aware of this; the question is how to deal with it appropriately (e.g., by clamping).

Comment: What I suspect is that either the numerator or denominator (or both) have been calculated and due to floating point arithmetic, down in the tail of the fractional part the numbers are not exact.  This leads to the situation I am seeing in that the end result should be exactly a value of 1 (I suspect) but is not due to floating point arithmetic being inexact.  So I'm curious to see if my assumption is correct what can I do to work around this situation and if not, then yes it could be spurious data from the source.